# How to parse Excel binary file structure?

Tags: excel, xlsx

I have parsed [PE files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) before. Does Excel have a similar structure to provide analysis, but I can't find relevant documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not clear (for instance, what do you mean by parsing, and what type of Excel files you mean are binaries), so I will try to guess.

Since you used the tag `xlsx` this perhaps solves your problem. `xlsx` files are simply zip files.
So you can change the extension to `zip`, and extract the contents.